# How to throw an error and return a widget in the same time in a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

I am using [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) as error monitoring that catch and store all errors occurred in my Flutter App. When I use the `FutureBuilder` widget, I handle the errors in the async function as follows:

```dart
Widget build(context){
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getData() // getting some data from an async function
        builder: (context, snap){
            if(snap.hasError){
                return Text('An error has occurred');
            }

            /// ...
            /// Doing something if there isn't an error
            /// ...
        }
    );
}
```

The problem here is that the error ocurred in `getData()` is not displayed in the console or in Sentry, because no error is thrown. I tried the following:

```dart
Widget build(context){
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getData() // getting some data from an async function
        builder: (context, snap){
            if(snap.hasError){
                thrown(snap.error); // this line was added
                return Text('An error has occurred');
            }

            /// ...
            /// Doing something if there isn't an error
            /// ...
        }
    );
}
```

In that case, the error is thrown and Sentry catches it, but the `Text()` widget doesn't return and nothing is shown in the app.

My question is if there is a way to throw the error for Sentry to catches it and returns a widget to show something in the app.

Comment: TL;DR Exceptions should only be used for exceptional circumstances. In the first codeblock, your `.hasError` block is handling the error, and as such there is no error to report to the console or to Sentry. In the second codeblock, you are manually throwing an error (which is what I assume your function `thrown()` is doing) and so control returns at that point. If you want to display the `Text`, and report to Sentry, I would manually write a non-fatal error message to Sentry, a `debugPrint` to the console and continue my processing in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Exceptions should only be used for exceptional circumstances.

In your first codeblock, your `.hasError` block is handling the error, and as such there is no exception to report to the console or to Sentry.

In the second codeblock, you are manually throwing an error (which is what I assume your function `thrown()` is doing) and so control ripples back up the stack from that point.

If you want to display the `Text` widget, and also report to Sentry, I would manually write a non-fatal error message to Sentry, write a `debugPrint` to the console and continue my processing in a normal, elegant way

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do that in this way:

```
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
              
              () async {
                if (snapshot.error is Exception) {
                  // throw to catch it in Zone for example  
                  throw snapshot.error as Exception;

                  // or send to Sentry 
                  Sentry.captureException(snapshot.error, error.stackTrace: stackTrace);
                }
              }.call();
    
              return Text('An error has occurred');
    }
```